# How to hide a sub-menu in Open ERP.?

Tags: odoo

How to hide submenus in OpenERP v7.0.

By creating a new group and add the unwanted menus into it.

But my problem is it most of the menus i selected will not disappeared . Any one please help to find a solution,.

Answer (score 0):

That should work although I wonder if the security on the underlying action or model is over-riding it - not sure.

However, another way is to create a module that depends on the module containing the menu you want to remove (so it is always installed after that module) and in an XML file do this.

```
<delete model="ir.ui.menu" id="project.menu_action_view_task" />
```

This definitely works in OpenERP 7.0. Remember the XML files just contain data instructions such as `<record>` etc. so you can manipulate existing records like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want not show any menu. Just create new users group and register  this submenu only to this group. Remember never register users to this group.